# Pom.XML Maven Build Dependency of POM Only Looking for Jar

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

**GIVEN:**
I have an in house tool built with gradle that includes a dependency that is only a POM file which in turn then includes a bunch of other dependencies.  No jar for this particular dependency by itself.  The tool builds.

I have a maven project with a pom.xml file that I want to include this tool in because of all the company specific methods needed for some processes.  I added the dependency with the type of pom and when I build it fails.

**ERROR:**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project <MYPROJECT>: Could not resolve dependencies for project <MYPROJECT>:jar:0.0.326: <com.pom.only.dependency>:jar:7.0 was not found in <Company Repo where this POM file exists> during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of <company repo> has elapsed or updates are forced
```

**REQUEST:**
I have tried making the tool a fat jar in the hopes it would not need this.  But it does.  The my project builds without this tool jar so I know it is this jar that brings in the dependency.  I just have no idea how to resolve this.

**ALMOST CODE EXAMPLE**
Because of company specific, I can not put the exact POM code but I can put what it looks like removing company specific stuff.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>tools-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>pom only dependency</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

So tools app is the one that I am pulling it.  It is the gradle build and uses the pom only dependency without any issue.  If I pull this into a gradle app it works fine and builds.  However, in the app that has this in the pom, if fails for above.  So I add the dependency for the pom only dependency and mark it as type pom but still get the error.

Comment: Did you add `<type>pom</type>` to the `<dependency>`?

Comment: Yes.  Still got the error.

Answer (score 1):

So for my situation (and not the best solution), I went into the dependency that has only a pom and pulled the dependencies out of there and built.  It worked.  But feel there should be a way to make it work without having to do this.